# Simple Html DOM fetch xpath

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, fetch

I am new to fetching, in code where it says `div[class="movies]/div/a`
I am trying to fetch all the tags with /a after div
it is only fetching only one, plz help me understand how to fetch all.

Thanks

```
<?php
include_once('../../simple_html_dom.php');

function scraping_IMDB($url) {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // get title/
    $ret['Title'] = $html->find('**div[class="movies]/div/a**', 0)->innertext;

    // get rating
    $ret['Rating'] = $html->find('div[class="DataWhite"] b', 0)->innertext;

    // get overview
    foreach($html->find('div[class="DataWhite"]') as $div) {
        // skip user comments
        if($div->find('h5', 0)->innertext=='User Comments:')
            return $ret;

        $key = '';
        $val = '';

        foreach($div->find('*') as $node) {
            if ($node->tag=='h5')
                $key = $node->plaintext;
            if ($node->tag=='a' && $node->plaintext!='more')
                $val .= trim(str_replace("\n", '', $node->plaintext));

            if ($node->tag=='text')
                $val .= trim(str_replace("\n", '', $node->plaintext));
        }

        $ret[$key] = $val;
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test it!
$ret = scraping_IMDB('http://www.tastekid.com/like/The+Help/movies');

foreach($ret as $k=>$v)
    echo '<strong>'.$k.' </strong>'.$v.'<br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what the code should be, but it's the "0" that's the problem.

```
// get title/
$ret['Title'] = $html->find('**div[class="movies]/div/a**', 0)->innertext;
```

to

```
// get title/
$ret['Title'] = $html->find('**div[class="movies]/div/a**')->innertext;
```

This will find *all* of the divs with class 'movies'. Because when you have ",0" it will only find the first. You will then need to iterate over the output of this like is done with the DataWhite class objects.

Comment: no I had tired tht too. doesn't look like tht is the problem <br> btw this is original code <br> `$ret['Title'] = $html->find('**div[class="movies]/div/a**', 0)->innertext;`